# Encode and decode string with special chars in client-server application

Tags: java, android, rest, encoding, utf-8

I'm developing my client-server application (server is like a servlet and client is an Android app). I have some difficulties sending information between two entities when the message has special chars (ie: 'è' or others)

On client side I use this code to send the message that can contain special chars:

```
public static String effettuaPOSTServer (String parameters) {
    try {
        byte [] parametersBytes = parameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL("http://" + IP_SERVER + ":" + PORT + PATH_SERVLET);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Length", String.valueOf (parametersBytes.length));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(parametersBytes);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        String s;

        while ((s = br.readLine ()) != null) {
            sb.append (s);
            sb.append ("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

on server side I use this code to send the response (also the response can contain special chars like 'è' and others) (I'm in servlet doPost context so I work with HttpServletRequest request and HttpServletResponse response):

```
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
...
String content = ...; //the string is formatted in JSON format
pw.println (content);
```

but on both sides I'm unable to receive and manage the correct strings where I have special chars.

I'm trying a lot of solutions on web about encoding/decoding etc. but without successful result.
How can I fix my problem? Thank you!

---

EDIT:
for example, immagine my request from client as follow (I report the request in GET format to show simply the case):

```
http://MY_URL:PORT/MY_PATH?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=èqualcosaacaso
```

but on server I receive:

```
parameter1=value1
parameter2=value2
parameter3=Äqualcosaacaso
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of expected and actual results?

Comment: @Lennier , please take a look at my EDIT. Thank you

Comment: Did you try to encode/decode your parameters to Base64?

Comment: not yet, now I would to send the info normally for a simple debug..next step will be base64 and compression like GZIP or deflate